# Kotlin Kapt failing - only sees android api level 1 sources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kapt

I'm seeing some weird behavior that causes `:app:kaptQaDebugKotlin` to fail when attempting to upgrade to android gradle plugin 3.0.

- method annotated with `@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` fails with `cannot find symbol` (`VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`)
- ...but `VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` when used inline with a method is found
- can't find symbol `DialogInterface.OnShowListener` (added in API level 8)
- ..but `DialogInteface.OnClickListener` is found (added in API level 1)
- cannot find symbol `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` (added in api level 14)
- note: Android Studio is able to see the source of all these `cannot find symbol` classes (`cmd + B`  works)

Versions

- compileSdkVersion: `25`
- buildTools: `26.0.2`
- Kotlin version: `1.1.51`
- AGP: `3.0.0`
- gradle wrapper: `4.3`
- Support lib: `24.2.1` (would be difficult to upgrade this too, but I did try `25.4.0` and still no luck)
- Dagger: `2.0.2` (stuck on this old version, can't upgrade unfortunately)
- use AGP 3.0.0 java 8 desugar feature
- using `kotlin-kapt` plugin. autovalue classes are correctly generated.

Any idea what's going on? It looks like the kapt task is somehow using android api level 1 sources, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that

Comment: Please share your gradle file. I have the same  problem because I changed the gradle incorrectly. If you have change it after upgrading, please show both versions.

Comment: I have the same issue, with realm and the auto generated proxy object from kapt. I've tried reproducing it in a new project, same error. Cannot find symbol @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB). Its driving me nuts. If i change gradle plugin to 2.3.2 - it works....

Comment: I mean when I create a new project with the same dependencies and the same versions - it compiles and it works, only for my working project i receive this error. which is very strange

Comment: Ive fixed it and for some reason the error was coming from external library logback-android-classic, i had to exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android' in the build.gradle and now it compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @pentarex

> error was coming from external library logback-android-classic, i had to exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android

```
implementation(libs.logbackAndroidClassic){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

Comment: It does indeed work. Do you have any explanation *why* does this fix this error? It doesn't seem to be connected in any way with the kapt error messages...